# @keyframes properties using many movements

Tags: css, css-animations

Could someone explain me how the extended rotation works in one @keyframes? I can understand easy movements, but it is incomprehensible for me to keep several turns in one @keyframes.

To illustrate it better I wrote @keyframes for both options:

Option A

```
@keyframes optionA1 {
  from {
    transform: rotateX(-20deg) rotateY(-30deg); 
  }
  to {
    transform: rotateX(-20deg)  rotate(-30deg);
  } 
}

@keyframes optionA2 {
  from {
    transform: rotateX(-20deg)  rotate(-30deg);
  }
  to {
    transform:  rotateX(-50deg) rotateZ(30deg) ;
  }
}
```

Object's animation: optionA1 (0-5s) optionA2 (5-10s)

Option B:

```
@keyframes optionB {
  from {
    transform: rotateX(-20deg) rotateY(-30deg); 
  }
  to {
    transform: rotateX(-20deg)  rotate(-30deg)
    rotateX(-50deg) rotateZ(30deg) ;
  } 
}
```

Object's animation: optionB (0-10s)

Why does not my object move the same when I used the same movements in keyframes?

How should I read the movements contained in the option b's keyframes?

How should I write option B for object's animation to be the same as in option A, but in one step - I do not want  the movement to stop for a moment?

Answer (score 1):

Try to split your last step in 2 steps:

```
@keyframes optionB {
  0% {
    transform: rotateX(-20deg) rotateY(-30deg); //start position
  }

  50% {
    transform: rotateX(-20deg)  rotate(-30deg); //5 sec

  } 

  100% {
    transform: rotateX(-50deg) rotateZ(30deg) ; //final position
  }

}
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried in this method, but it solution causes that movements stop for a moment (in 50%). I want that movement continous, so I tried to write this in one step. Maybe there is another method?

Comment: @kolekole could you please add your code as a code snippet into your answer or as a demo on the Codepen?

Comment: @kolekole here I've just implemented the solution https://codepen.io/nat-davydova/pen/2790b785b829e533e09f84f1fd93abdb and can't see any stop through the animation, do you have this pause if you check my example?

Comment: https://codepen.io/kolekole/pen/BXBOXd it is my project. is for extended animation, and I wanted to understand how to make a very complex move in one step. In "anima" I divided it into%. The first solution I have from {} to{}

Comment: @kolekole you can apply only 1 transform move in a step, anyway =(

Comment: @kolekole I mean you can't transform rotateX 2 times in 1 animation phase

Comment: As I understand correctly, for example, only one rotateX () works in the whole step? The only option is to add a few steps (your example) or several animations (option A)?

Thank you very much for your time! :) So I spent weeks unnecessarily, because it can not be done in one step, which I did not know. Best regards!